# Setting state does not change the value in GoogleMaps addListener

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

Very simple case, but I can't find the way out!

I have a Google map with a single marker. The "click" listener callback function logs the state's value.
I added a button that changes the state's value, and a `useEffect` hook that logs the state value when it is changed, just to check it has changed.

Problem: when I change the state value from "false" to "true" with the button, the hook is triggered and logs the new value ("true"), so I'm pretty sure the state has changed. BUT when I click on the marker, it still returns the previous value ("False") of the state.

How can I get the marker "click" callback to use the updated value of the state?

Thank you for your help, I'm stuck and I could find no support on this issue!

My code (a small and simplified extract of a bigger project!).

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function MapPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)
  
  // GoogleMap loading with @react-google-maps/api
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
      id: 'google-map-script',
      googleMapsApiKey: "MY-API-KEY"
  })

  // Marker creation with officiel GoogleMaps API
  const onLoad = useCallback(function callback(map) {
    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: 43.3318, lng: 5.0550 },
      icon : { url : "/static/NotSubscribed.svg", scaledSize : {width:60, height:60}}
    });
    marker.addListener("click", () => {console.log("Marker clicked - State is : " + state)}); 
  }, [])

  // useEffect to display new state when value changed
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect - State is : " + state)
  }, [state])

  return (isLoaded ? (
    <Box width="100%" height="100%">
      <GoogleMap 
        mapContainerStyle={{ position: "fixed", height:"100%", width: "100%"}}
        center={{ lat: 43.3318, lng: 5.0550 }}
        zoom={15}                
        onLoad={onLoad}
      >
      </GoogleMap>
      <Box sx={{position : "fixed", top : 200, right : 200, width : 50, height : 50, backgroundColor : "black"}}
          onClick={() => setState(true)}
        />
    </Box>
  ) : <></>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const onLoad = useCallback(function callback(map) {
    let marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: 43.3318, lng: 5.0550 },
      icon : { url : "/static/NotSubscribed.svg", scaledSize : {width:60, height:60}}
    });
    marker.addListener("click", () => {console.log("Marker clicked - State is : " + state)}); 
  }, [])
```

since dependency array is empty, this function is created once and reads state when the function is built. Although, you are adding `[state]` to use `useEffect`, this rerenders the component but it does not re create the `useCallback` callback function. you have to add same dependency `[state]` to use `useCallback`

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that the listener callback was "cached" when the object is created, it explains my issue. Unfortunately my real code is much more complex (it was just an example) and I can not trigger the hook each time the state changed. So I have chosen as the solution to have a changeState function as the callback. Thank you for the explanation, it will be useful for my next listeners !

Answer (score 1):

### You could use `<Marker />` component with onClick props from `react-google-maps/api` library

What @Yilmaz said is correct, but since you are also using `react-google-maps/api` library, it would be much simpler for you to use `<Marker />` component since it has an `onClick` prop.

ref: https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker

### Here's what you can do:

Create a `changeState` function to toggle the state between `true` and `false` using ternary operator (This is just for testing).

```
const changeState = () => {
    state === false ? setState(true) : setState(false);
  };
```

Create a `markerClicked` function to put on your `<Marker />` `onClick` props.

```
const markerClicked = (e) => {
    // You can use the 'e' parameter if you want to get the event of the click.
    // For now, we'll just log the current state per marker click
    console.log("Marker clicked - State is : " + state);
  };
```

Then here's what your components should look like along with these changes:

```
  return isLoaded ? (
    <Box width="100%" height="100%">
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{ position: "fixed", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        center={location}
        zoom={15}
        onLoad={onLoad}
      >
        {/* Here I used the <Marker /> component instead of the vanilla way
        of rendering a marker on the map */}
        <Marker position={location} onClick={markerClicked} />
      </GoogleMap>
      <Box
        sx={{
          position: "fixed",
          top: 200,
          right: 200,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: "black"
        }}
        onClick={changeState}
      />
    </Box>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
```

With this, when the map gets loaded, it logs `useEffect - State is : false` since that was your default `state` value. Then when you click on the marker, it will also log the current state `Marker clicked - State is : false`.

To test if it is working properly, you can toggle the state between `true` and `false` by clicking the box, then clicking the marker after it to see if the returned state is the same.

Here's a working sandbox for you to test for yourself:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proof-of-concept-sandbox-log-the-state-per-marker-click-and-change-state-per-box-click-ok4vc0?file=/src/Map.js

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Changing the state with the callback function really is a good idea.

Comment: Regarding <Marker>, I used it before, but I had very annoying bugs that would have been very difficult to overcome. So I have decided to replace all with official GoogleMaps objects and now it's much more simple and renders and much easier to control. I still use react-google-maps/API to mount the map, but I will soon remove it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Glad I was still able to help!